# Web app freezes when button click function executed, but only in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

This has stumped me for the past day and a half. I'm running a function to highlight cells in a gridview. When I click a span to turn off the feature, the whole page freezes. This does not happen on chrome or firefox. Only Safari.

The offending function is "document.getElementById('markbutton').onclick". It works if the sub function "coordsync" is empty. If it has anything, even just an "alert("hello")", the whole page freezes in Safari. It's incredibly frustrating.

Relevant code:

```
var highlightstate = 0;
document.getElementById('markbutton').onclick = function () {
if (highlightstate == 0) {
    document.getElementById('highlightnotif').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('markbutton').style.backgroundColor = "#FFDB4D";
    highlightstate = 1;
}
else if (highlightstate == 1) {
    document.getElementById('highlightnotif').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('markbutton').style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFF0";
    highlightstate = 0;
    coordsync();
}

}

function coordsync() {
var txcoords = [];
var selectlist = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
for (i = 0; i < selectlist.length; i++) {
    var row = selectlist[i].parentNode.rowIndex;
    var column = selectlist[i].cellIndex;
    txcoords.push(row + "," + column);
}
alert(txcoords.join('$'));
}

var table = $("#gridviewSLds tbody");

function hasClass(element, cls) {
return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
var txttimelist = document.getElementsByClassName("txttime");
for (i = 0; i < txttimelist.length; i++) {
txttimelist[i].onclick = function (e) {
    hightouchstart(e)
}
txttimelist[i].ontouchmove = function (e) {
    resethighTimer();
    hightouchmove(e)
}
}

function hightouchstart(e) {
if (highlightstate == 1) {
    var cell = e.currentTarget;
    if (hasClass(e.target, 'selected')) {
        cell.classList.remove("selected");
        startCellIndex = cell.index();
        startRowIndex = cell.parent().index();
        removal = 1;
    }
    else {
        cell.classList.add('selected');
        startCellIndex = cell.index();
        startRowIndex = cell.parent().index();
        removal = 0;
    }

    return false;
}
else {
    modaltxttime(e);
}
}

var first = 0;
var hightimermsec = 200;
var highTimer;
function resethighTimer() {
if (highlightstate == 1) {
    clearTimeout(highTimer);
    highTimer = setTimeout(sethightime, hightimermsec);
}
}
var hightime = 1;
function sethightime() {
resethighTimer();
hightime = 1;
dispX = 0;
dispY = 0;
moveselect = 0;
}

var removal = 0;
var dispX = 0;
var dispY = 0;
var moveselect = 0;
function hightouchmove(e) {
if (highlightstate == 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    var moveX = touch.clientX - dispX;
    var moveY = touch.clientY - dispY;
    if (moveselect == 0) {
        if (dispX != 0) {
            if (Math.abs(moveY) < 12 * Math.abs(moveX)) {
                var scrollleft = document.getElementById('scrollcontaindiv2').scrollLeft;
                document.getElementById('scrollcontaindiv2').scrollLeft = scrollleft - moveX;
                dispX = touch.clientX;
                dispY = touch.clientY;
                moveselect = 1;
            }
            else {
                var cell = document.elementFromPoint(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
                if (hightime == 1) {
                    hightime = 0;
                    if (hasClass(cell, 'txttime')) {
                        if (hasClass(e.target, 'selected')) {
                            cell.classList.remove('selected');
                            removal = 1;
                        }
                        else {
                            cell.classList.add('selected');
                            removal = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (hasClass(cell, 'txttime') == true) {
                        if (removal == 0) {
                            cell.classList.add('selected');
                        }
                        else if (removal == 1) {
                            cell.classList.remove("selected");
                        }
                    }
                }
                moveselect = 2;
            }
        }
        else {
            dispX = touch.clientX;
            dispY = touch.clientY;
        }
    }
    else if (moveselect == 1) {
        var scrollleft = document.getElementById('scrollcontaindiv2').scrollLeft;
        document.getElementById('scrollcontaindiv2').scrollLeft = scrollleft - moveX;
        dispX = touch.clientX;
        dispY = touch.clientY;
    }
    else if (moveselect == 2) {
        var cell = document.elementFromPoint(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
        if (hightime == 1) {
            hightime = 0;
            if (hasClass(cell, 'txttime')) {
                if (hasClass(e.target, 'selected')) {
                    cell.classList.remove('selected');
                    removal = 1;
                }
                else {
                    cell.classList.add('selected');
                    removal = 0;
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            if (hasClass(cell, 'txttime') == true) {
                if (removal == 0) {
                    cell.classList.add('selected');
                }
                else if (removal == 1) {
                    cell.classList.remove("selected");
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: I've seen something similar happen, can you try doing a ```preventDefault()``` first and then do the rest of the processing?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. I have no idea why it works. But it does.
The super weird thing is that adding an alert to the bottom of that function breaks it.

Relevant changes to the markbutton function:

```
document.getElementById('markbutton').onclick = function (e) {
if (highlightstate == 0) {
    document.getElementById('highlightnotif').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('markbutton').style.backgroundColor = "#FFDB4D";
    highlightstate = 1;
    var txttimelist = document.getElementsByClassName("txttime");
    for (i = 0; i < txttimelist.length; i++) {
        txttimelist[i].onclick = function highclickev(e) {
            hightouchstart(e);
        }
        txttimelist[i].ontouchmove = function highdragev(e) {
            resethighTimer();
            hightouchmove(e);
        }
    }
}
else if (highlightstate == 1) {
    highlightstate = 0;

    selectlist = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
    for (i = 0; i < selectlist.length; i++) {
        var row = selectlist[i].parentNode.rowIndex;
        var column = selectlist[i].cellIndex;
        txcoords.push(row + "," + column);
    }
    document.getElementById('highlightnotif').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('markbutton').style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFF0";

    txttimelist = document.getElementsByClassName("txttime");
    for (i = 0; i < txttimelist.length; i++) {
        txttimelist[i].removeEventListener('onclick', highclickev);
        txttimelist[i].removeEventListener('ontouchmove', highdragev);
        txttimelist[i].onclick = function regclickev(e) {
            modaltxttime(e);
        }
    }
    txcoords.join('$');
}
```

}